# What is the proper way of denoting URI with diacritics (letters with accents)?

Tags: perl, uri, url-encoding, diacritics

What is the correct and official way of using diacritics in URI?

I have 3 different ways shown below:

1. Here `á` = `%E1`, `â` = `%E2`, space = `%20`, comma = `%2C`, but this link doesn't work properly since the characters are mangled:

   ```
   http://www.recordspreservation.org/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi?directory=%2CBrasil%2CGoi%E1s%2CLuzi%E2nia%2CSanta%20Luzia%2CBatismos%201749-1753%2CImagens&image_name=_MG_5229.JPG
   ```
2. Here space = `%20`, comma = `%2C` and I don't do anything with the a's. This link works:

   ```
   http://www.recordspreservation.org/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi?directory=%2CBrasil%2CGoiás%2CLuziânia%2CSanta%20Luzia%2CBatismos%201749-1753%2CImagens&image_name=_MG_5229.JPG
   ```
3. Here space = `+`, comma = `%2C` and I don't do anything with the a's. This link works:

   ```
   http://www.recordspreservation.org/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi?directory=%2CBrasil%2CGoiás%2CLuziânia%2CSanta+Luzia%2CBatismos+1749-1753%2CImagens&image_name=_MG_5229.JPG
   ```

Comment: I was using uri_escape and when I use uri_escape_utf then I get this URI which works. The ones without the vowels escaped are more legible. What is the official way of doing this? http://www.recordspreservation.org/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi?directory=%2CBrasil%2CGoi%C3%A1s%2CLuzi%C3%A2nia%2CSanta%20Luzia%2CBatismos%201749-1753%2CImagens&image_name=_MG_5229.JPG

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear in my answer. All of this is described in [***RFC 3986***](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-3986.txt), which confirms what I wrote below. Officially, a URL may use only a restricted subset of 7-bit ASCII, and anything else must be percent-encoded. If you need to use a character outside 7-bit ASCII then it must be UTF-8-encoded, and the resulting bytes percent-encoded. It sounds like you have a server that allows you to break the rules, and I have no way of knowing what the new less-restrictive rules are, but you shouldn't rely on anything beyond the standard.

Answer (score 3):

The characters in a URL string must be within in a restricted subset of 7-bit ASCII, and no encoding is specified for wide characters

Some of that set are ***unreserved***, and may be used literally anywhere the syntax allows

The remaining characters are ***reserved*** because they form part of the URL syntax; reserved characters must be percent-encoded if they are used outside their syntactical meaning

Eight-bit characters that are in neither the *reserved* nor the *unreserved* categories must always be percent-encoded

##Unreserved characters

```
0 to 9
A to Z
a to z
-
.
_
~
```

##Reserved characters

```
! - %21
# - %23
$ - %24
& - %26
' - %27
( - %28
) - %29
* - %2A
+ - %2B
, - %2C
/ - %2F
: - %3A
; - %3B
= - %3D
? - %3F
@ - %40
[ - %5B
] - %5D
```

> This link doesn't work properly since the characters are mangled

That is a problem between the client and the server. It looks like you're sending ISO-8859-1 characters, in which scheme `E1` and `E2` correspond to *e acute*, and *e circumflex*. But if your server is expecting UTF-8 encoding then those should appear as byte sequences `C3 A1` and `C3 A2`

I can't tell what encoding is expected by your server, but it clearly isn't what you're sending. The [current standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) is to encode non-ASCII characters in UTF-8 and percent-encode the resulting bytes

---

###Update

The best solution is to use the [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module, which will encode character string as necessary

***Take special note that, if you need to use UTF-8-encoded characters in your source code, as below, then you must have `use utf8` at the top of your program. You also need to make sure that your editor is writing UTF-8 data to the program file.***

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use URI;

my $url = URI->new('http://www.recordspreservation.org/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi?directory=,Brasil,Goiás,Luziânia,Santa Luzia,Batismos 1749-1753,Imagens&image_name=_MG_5229.JPG');

say $url;
```

###output

```
http://www.recordspreservation.org/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi?directory=,Brasil,Goi%C3%A1s,Luzi%C3%A2nia,Santa%20Luzia,Batismos%201749-1753,Imagens&image_name=_MG_5229.JPG
```

Comment: The letters with accents seem to work without encoding. Is that acceptable? I am expecting UTF8 data and that's my problem. I should be sending UTF8.

Comment: I think I'm going to need to see your code. This could work if the server is expecting UTF-8, and your editor is generating and displaying UTF-8 but you don't have `use utf8` in place at the top of your program.

Comment: Officially, anything other than 7-bit ASCII is illegal in a URL

Comment: @MarcosCamargo: Please take note of the update to my answer.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I will use the URI module and avoid the non-7 bit ASCII.

Comment: @MarcosCamargo: Does the URL under **output** in my answer work correctly?

Comment: This is a nice one :)